# Using foreach with substr() to modify variable names

Tags: foreach, stata

I have a set of variables, the names of which have the same prefix attached to unique two-digit years:

```
div_unemp03
div_unemp04
.
.
.
div_unemp14
```

I would like to rename these variables to be as follows:

```
div_ue03
div_ue04
.
.
.
div_ue14
```

I attempted to carry this out using a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach x of var unemp*  {
    local new = substr(`x', 10, 2)
    rename `x' div_ue`new'
}
```

However, Stata produces an error code:

> type mismatch

Any help in understanding this error and how to achieve the desired effect would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `substr` function requires a **string** as its first argument. Additionally, your varlist syntax `unemp*` will not catch the variables named `div_unemp##`, since they do not *begin* with `unemp` (generating the "type mismatch" error). The (reproducible) example below shows both corrections.

```
clear
input div_unemp03 div_unemp04 div_unemp05
1 1 1
end

foreach x of varlist *unemp* {
    local new = substr("`x'", 10, 2)
    rename `x' div_ue`new'
}
```

Note also that `substr()` allows you to count from the *end* of the string, so `substr("s", -2, 2)` works.

Comment: Note also in this case scope for using `subinstr()` to zap the `mp`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing in one line by simply using the `rename` command:

```
clear
set obs 1

forvalues i = 3 / 6 {
    generate div_unemp0`i' = .
}

list, abbreviate(11)

     +-------------------------------------------------------+
     | div_unemp03   div_unemp04   div_unemp05   div_unemp06 |
     |-------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |           .             .             .             . |
     +-------------------------------------------------------+

rename div_unemp# div_ue#

list, abbreviate(10)

     +-------------------------------------------+
     | div_ue03   div_ue04   div_ue05   div_ue06 |
     |-------------------------------------------|
  1. |        .          .          .          . |
     +-------------------------------------------+
```